# What is bitcode for apple iOS apps, does need to do the developer extra effort

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, llvm

I heard recently that apple for iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional for app thinning. Does developer need to change something in the code except the plist modification `Enable Bitcode`. I didn't find much about bitcode. How can a developer make app compatible with this and its architecture to more robust app.

I have read below documents, please suggestest me some resource for deep study and implementation of bitcode on apple iOS:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8991

https://medium.com/@InertialLemon/apple-s-bitcode-telegraphs-future-cpu-plans-a7b90d326228